# Invalid Object Name when i execute a procedure that update a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have  the following

```
use salesdb
go

create procedure monthlysales as
begin

create table MyTable( SalesFactID integer identity(1,1),
ReportingMth date, 
customer_id varchar(50),
ReferenceID navarchar(50), 
LstOrderDte date);

Insert into MyTable

select 
businessMth,
saleid as referenceid,
null as lastorderte

from sourcetble;

update MyTable
set lastorderte = sls.max_orderdte
from ( select
st.customer_id,
ftmytbl.ReportingMth,
max(salesdate) as max_orderdte

from sales_table st

left outer join mytable ftmytbl
on ftmytbl.customerid=st.customerRef

where saleste<=ftmytbl.ReportingMth 

group by customer_id 

)up

where mytable.customer_id=up.customer_id
and mytable.reportingmth=up.ReportingMth;

end;

execute monthlysales
```

> error invalid object name mytable.reportingmth

How can i fix this? Please assist.

Comment: Whitespace is a wonderful thing. I really strongly suggest you use it. That code is very hard to read as it's all left aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Search for that text. Where is it? It is in the where clause of the outermost select statement. You used a derived table named up (which is a crap name, btw - as are many of your names) in the join. The outer query knows only 2 tables - up and MyTable (or is it mytable? BE CONSISTENT!) and can only refer to columns in those tables.

To correct this particular problem, change this:

```
and mytable.reportingmth=up.ReportingMth;
```

to

```
and MyTable.ReportingMth = up.ReportingMth;
```

But that will only fix one problem. There seem to be others yet to be found.

Comment: Thanks. However whitespace is not making any difference. still having the same issue.

Comment: MyTable and mytable are one and same.

Comment: Does installed MDAC has an effect on this as i see one similar case like this??